# Log filtering using markers in java

Tags: java, slf4j, java.util.logging

In my project we had been using java.util.logging for the logs and now we want to apply markers and filter those markers according to our need. So is there any way to use markers using just java.util and slf4j framework.
Because we can't change the existing things or it will increase the work significantly.